# Blind disease in Hens

Tags: health, death, chickens, sight

It's rainy season here. The hens and cocks are affected by a type of disease in the eyes. The eyes remain closed and swollen. The hens remain motionless and eventually die. It is spreading to other hens also. What we did was to rub some lemon on the eyes.

Can some one give insight on this sickness and it's cures 
[image: blind hen-b]

Comment: they need a vet,and this might be dangerous for people too.can you give more details about this illness like do other hens in your area have it and is this only happening in the wet season.more details is needed to give you any advice.

Comment: Eyes get swollen and the chicken sits in one place or stands on one leg for indefinite time.

Comment: Interested in natural cures only

Comment: Please do not put lemon in their eyes, this needs medical attention - there are no natural cures.

Comment: Are you putting lemon in their eyes to try and help them? Lemon is acidic and will burn the eyes and possibly cause blindness. It's actually a cruel thing to do - even if the intentions are good.